# How to convert string formula to a mathematical formula in C#

Tags: c#

If I have a string variable with a formula:

```
string myformula = "3 * 5 + Pow(2,3)";
```

How can I convert this string to a mathematical formula that the compiler can calculate?

Comment: For something the compiler can calculate you need a constant expression in the code, so something akin to `3 * 5 + 2 * 2 *2`. Don't you mean that your own code should evaluate it?

Comment: Finally I got the FLEE library. The tool is free and perfectly fit for this purpose.

Comment: The FLEE library is at http://flee.codeplex.com/, and it does look very good. Why not write your own answer to this question (which is allowed/encouraged), so the question shows as answered, and others can up-vote your answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I got the [FLEE](http://flee.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) library for this purpose. The tool is free and perfectly fit for your purpose. 
Below is an example how to use this library:

```
// Define the context of our expression
ExpressionContext context = new ExpressionContext();
// Allow the expression to use all static public methods of System.Math
context.Imports.AddType(typeof(Math));
// Define an int variable
context.Variables["a"] = 100;
// Create a dynamic expression that evaluates to an Object
IDynamicExpression eDynamic = context.CompileDynamic("sqrt(a) + pi");
// Evaluate the expressions
double result = (double)eDynamic.Evaluate();
```

Comment: It meanwhile moved to github: https://github.com/mparlak/Flee

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why would you mention a compiler, but the simplest way will be to use a math expression evaluator, for example [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/).

Comment: meanwhile also moved to github: https://github.com/ncalc/ncalc

Answer (score 0):

You could add a reference to Microsoft Script Control Library (COM) and use code like this to evaluate an expression. (Also works for JScript.)

```
MSScriptControl.ScriptControl sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
sc.Language = "VBScript";
string expression = "1 + 2 * 7";
object result = sc.Eval(expression);            
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```